# Spring framework work with JDK javac 16.0.2 in Netbeans?

Tags: java, spring

```
Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O
failure during classpath scanning; nested exception is
org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to
parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that
isn't supported yet: class path resource
[springanotaciones/ComercialExp.class]; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major
version 60
```

```java
package springanotaciones;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext contexto = new 
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        
    Empleado pipi = contexto.getBean("comercial", Empleado.class);
        
    System.out.println(pipi.setInforme());

    }
}
```

```java
package springanotaciones;

public interface Empleado {
    
    public String setTarea();
    public String setInforme();
    
}
```

```
package springanotaciones;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("comercial")
public class ComercialExp implements Empleado {

    @Override
    public String setTarea() {
    
        return"vender y vernder";
    }

    @Override
    public String setInforme() {
        
    
        return"El comercial genero un informe";
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    ">
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="springanotaciones"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

Comment: Judging by your xml you are using Spring 3.1, which doesn't support anything after 8 (if it already supports 8 as that was officially in 3.2). So either downgrade java to something < 8 or upgrade Spring to 5.x (as that has support for java 8+).

Answer (score 0):

Right,the problem was the JDK16¡

finally I change de JDK 16 for the JDK 14 for this project and is working, maybe this help someone in the future.

Sorry for my inglish.

Comment: Depending on which version of Spring and related frameworks you use this might eventually also break. I strongly suggest to use the supported max. version for the version of Spring you are intending to use.